# How to integrate Captcha (Recaptcha) for WTForms in CherryPy

Tags: python, recaptcha, cherrypy, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I want to use a `RecaptchaField()` in my WTForms, such as:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Your name', [InputRequired(message='Please enter your name!')])
    recaptcha = RecaptchaField() # RecaptchaField as provided by Flask-WTF
    submit = SubmitField('Send')
```

Since I am using CherryPy, I am not sure whether or not I should use Flask-WTF, because Flask is a whole framework itself. I am wondering if I can use the Recaptcha functionality of Flask-WTF within my CherryPy solution. I tried the following:

```
from wtforms import StringField
from wtforms.validators import InputReqired
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask.ext.wtf.recaptcha import RecaptchaField

# ...

form = MyForm() # Somewhere in my code
```

as seen in [this Example here](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/master/examples/recaptcha/app.py). I get the following Exception:

```
RuntimeError: working outside of application context
```

It means I have to properly set up a Flask app considering the right context... This is where I am starting to wonder if I am doing the right approach. Is there no other way than set up a separate Flask app inside my CherryPy app??

Comment: I toyed with repactcha and it was helpful however we found if we added an invisible input tag the scripts would enter text in that field while no user would ever see the element.  Let me know if you still want the recaptcha code.

Comment: @Andrew Kloos yes, can you share your code?

Comment: Turns out we stopped recapcha a while back and I no longer have the code.  But here's the example I used... https://github.com/google/recaptcha

Comment: @AndrewKloos your example seems to be in php. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is mostly relevant to CherryPy and reCaptcha parts of the question. In my opinion, usage of WTForms and other similar libraries leads to a design problem when, speaking in terms of MVC-like design, you scatter the view and the controller into your own code and WTForms code/configuration. Things are simple when you manage one thing in a single place. Thus I suggest to use template engine like [Jinja2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Jinja2) for the view (you can create a macro for a repetitive form element) and use input validation library like [voluptuous](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/voluptuous) in the controller (you can use same schema for form and API validation).

If you can't avoid WTForms, just grab `validateRecaptcha` and turn it into [WTForms custom validator](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6/validators.html#custom-validators).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


import urllib
import json

import cherrypy
import voluptuous as volu


config = {
  'global' : {
    'server.socket_host' : '127.0.0.1',
    'server.socket_port' : 8080,
    'server.thread_pool' : 8
  },
  '/' : {
    'recaptcha' : {
        # By default, all keys work on localhost
       'siteKey' : '6LeYIbsSAAAAACRPIllxA7wvXjIE411PfdB2gt2J',
       'secret'  : '6LeYIbsSAAAAAJezaIq3Ft_hSTo0YtyeFG-JgRtu'
     }
  }
}

def validateRecaptcha(value):
  '''https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify'''

  if 'g-recaptcha-response' not in cherrypy.request.params:
    raise volu.Invalid('Recaptcha response is missing') 

  payload = urllib.urlencode({
    'secret'   : cherrypy.request.config['recaptcha']['secret'],
    'remoteip' : cherrypy.request.headers['remote-addr'],
    'response' : cherrypy.request.params['g-recaptcha-response']
  })

  url      = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
  response = json.load(urllib.urlopen(url, payload))
  if not response['success']:
    cherrypy.log(str(response))
    raise volu.Invalid(response['error-codes'])


class App:

  @cherrypy.expose
  def index(self, **kwargs):
    form = dict(form = {'value': ''}, errors = '')

    if cherrypy.request.method == 'POST':
      schema = volu.Schema({
        'value'                : volu.All(unicode, volu.Length(min = 8, max = 16)),
        'g-recaptcha-response' : validateRecaptcha,
      }, required = True, extra = True)
      try:
        kwargs = schema(kwargs)
      except volu.MultipleInvalid as ex:
        form = dict(form = kwargs, errors = {e.path[0] for e in ex.errors})
      else:
        raise cherrypy.HTTPRedirect('#success')

    return '''<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>reCAPTCHA demo</title>
          <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <form action="/" method="POST">
            <div style='border: 1px red solid'>{errors}</div>
            <div>Name</div>
            <input type="text" name="value" value="{form[value]}"/>
            <br/>
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{0}"></div>
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
    '''.format(cherrypy.request.config['recaptcha']['siteKey'], **form)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  cherrypy.quickstart(App(), '/', config)
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! I am already in line with MVC model since I am using WTForms in the controller and Mako for the view (or do i not get your point there?). I guess the main problem is that the RecaptchaField is made for Flask and not for CherryPy so the implementation would be kind of painful, I guess I go best with a custom validator as you suggest. I'll give that a try and let you know.

Comment: @Flaudre I meant that having Mako and WTForms, both outputing HTML which you need to compose, effectively you end up ~1.5 view layers which is not always desired. Also, WTForms configuration itself, for instance when you need to set at attribute to generated INPUT tag, mixes concerns because most likely you'll do it in controller code. But for simple cases, I think, WTForms will work fine and can save some time at the start. For more complex cases and cases that need more flexibility and control over HTML I wouldn't recommend it.